# Why are my iOS events firing in the wrong order?

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer, touchscreen, touchesbegan

I'm working an iPhone app called RealBaseball.  If you're familiar with RealSoccer, it's pretty similar.  It will allow you to play baseball with your iPhone with friends around the world.

When you hit the iPhone screen with your conductive bat, it should first detect the touch event then detect the acceleration so it knows exactly when you hit it, and how hard and how fast.

This is where I'm running into some technical difficulties.  I have the standard `touchesBegan` and `didAccelerate` listeners.  The problem is that `didAccelerate` is firing before `touchesBegan`.  Clearly, something is wrong since it shouldn't start accelerating before the bat touches it.  Could I be missing setup code?

I need to fix this, because if the timing is wrong, the batting machine on the other end will be laggy, and it won't be any fun.

Any advice you can provide would be appreciated.

EDIT: I added some NSLog calls with formatted `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];`  Here's the output:

```
didAccelerate: 1364850400.03221
touchesBegan: 1364850400.21486
```

So you can see it's a small but clear difference.

Comment: Can you put in some debug statements and list the output here or on pastebin or something?  I think I have a hunch what's wrong but some solid facts never hurt :)

Comment: Is the phone placed on a flat surface, or are you holding it in your hand? Also, did you try using the CoreMotion framework and read the timestamp property from the CMLogItem class?

Comment: @Lefteris, the batting machine on this end throws it then I hit it with the conductive bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you ensuring the bat is closing the conductive circuit from the phone to your hand?  I'd suggest copious use of the material used to make gloves touchscreen friendly.  Silver-threaded nylon is recommended here: http://www.howtogeek.com/130477/diy-touch-screen-mod-makes-regular-gloves-smartphone-friendly/

UPDATE: Oh, you might need to amplify the very tiny current that the bat will experience so it can travel all the way to your hand.  I'm not an electrician but a portable car battery attached to the bat via the same thread should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried the car battery technique, and let's just say I am no longer concerned about my original problem.